# Database design for achievement system

Tags: sql-server, database

I just started learning about databases and therefore i need a bit of help with the design of my database. I am trying to make an achievment system and I am a bit stuck mostly because im worried my design isn´t that good. I have come up with 2 solutions the first is show here: [link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsfPX.jpg).

So basicly I got a user who has some ingameData. There will be a record of every game he has played and therefor I don't need data like total[xyz], where xyz could be any stat as I can just get those with queries. My problem lies on the other side. I got Many users who got many Achievments.

What I have learned so far is that you should always have your forigen key in your many relation table so I would need to add another table as shown here in my 2 solution: [Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22DBO.png). Here I have that Many users has one achievement table and many achievments belong to one achievment table. Is my connectivity wrong here? and/or is my design really flawed? This is my first real datebase design, so I am a bit clueless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard way to model a many to many is to introduce a link table. You create a link between the User and the Achievement.

Conventionally called UserAchievement this contains two columns UserId and AchievementId both fks to their respective table.

When an achievement is gained you just add another entry.

Comment: Ahh yes I remember reading about this. Would the UserAchievement table need a primary key + the two fk keys? I think I read every table should have a primary key

Comment: @Sumsar1812, You must decide, whether one achievement can be earned multiple times or not... If this is a "once per person" issue, you can use the two FKs - but I would not... As long as you do not add further information to this relation table (e.g. date of earning, special circumstances...) there's no need for a PK (but do create an index on the FKs!). I'd add an identity column as PK. You'll probably need it in the future...

Comment: @Shnugo Ah I see that makes sence. Yea Achievments are one per person. I would think extra data like date of earning I would just add it to the Achievment table and not the linking table. Im not 100% sure what you mean by an index of the FKs, wouldn't the link table already hold that by having the two FKs?

Comment: @Sumsar1812, Information which belongs to the couple (user/achievement) must be placed within the linking table (or below it). "Date of earning" cannot be part of your achievements table. This is kind of a catalogue... The point with the index is easy: While questioning your data you'll have many, many joins between your "base" tables and the linking table. Indexes will speed this up...

Comment: Oh alright, yea I can see the part of indexing to be smart. Thanks for the answers